# How to draw this border in XAML

Tags: xaml

[image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

This is an interesting question.
For the first picture, in XAML, we can easily draw it with a Border:

Border Width="10" Height="10" CorderRadius="0,10,0,0" Background="Red"

The remaining part of the area is transparent.

However, How can I draw the second picture with reverse colors, using Border, while keep the uncolored area transparent?

### Thanks.

I can do it now，thank you, I am so happy :)

[image]

Comment: Hi @punker76, both Meee and I can see it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create a path

```
 <Path Data="M0,0 L20,0 L19.4838,0.006531 C8.84821,0.275986 0.275986,8.84821 0.006531,19.4838 L0,20 z" Fill="Red" Height="10" Stretch="Fill" Width="10"/>
```

You can achieve this using Blend. Draw a rectangle and an ellipse like this

[image: BlendImage]

Select both the ellipse and the rectangle together (but make sure you select ellipse first and rectangle second). Then right click (Combine -> Subtract).

[image: BlendSteps]

Comment: How to do this? Did you use blend? Do you have any recommendations on blend tutorials? Thanks!